# Can member developer upload build on test-flight distribution?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I have a query, Client has invited me as a Member Developer in their member center, so i have limited access. My question is that: Shall i upload the build on the appStore(test-flight) for the testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, if the client gave you permission to do this (for the member center and also for the iTunes Connect)